# What is this native North American ground cover?

Tags: identification, ground-cover

Oops, planted it and lost the tag. It's growing quite happily in zone 5A (USDA zone 4) in light shade and clay soil.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like [Chrysogonum virginianum.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Chrysogonum+virginianum&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NFi9U-jPHMfYoAS-y4HACQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1426&bih=658)  Here is an [excerpt from a nursery site](http://www.viette.com/v.php?pg=721):

> Commonly known as Goldenstar or Green and Gold, Chrysogonum virginianum is a beautiful wildflower that is native to the eastern United States. It is one of the finest flowering ground covers for the sun or shade garden, bearing bright yellow star-shaped flowers that will lighten up even a patch of deep shade.